# Saving a Parse object from within a Backbone event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm using Backbone.js and [Parse](https://parse.com) for persistence. I'm trying to save a parse object when a Backbone event fires, but it's not working. Here's my code (edited to remove unnecessary stuff):

```
Parse.initialize("abc123", "omgwtf");

var ListsView = Parse.View.extend({
    events: {
        "submit form": "newList"
    },
    newList: function() {       
        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
        var gameScore = new GameScore();

        gameScore.set("score", 2222);
        gameScore.set("playerName", "Mike Hunt");
        gameScore.set("cheatMode", true);

        gameScore.save(null, {
            success: function(gameScore) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(gameScore, error) {
                alert("error: " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

My error alert is showing, but the error message is an empty string. The Parse object saves just fine when my saving code is at the same top-level scope as the `Parse.initialize` method.  I'm in the process of learning Javascript, so any background on why this code isn't working would be awesome.

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but have you tried putting the Parse.Object.extend("GameScore"); outside the new list method? Then instead set it when you create a new Instance of ListView. EX: lists = new ListsView; lists.gameScoreObject = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore"); Then lastly, inside your newList method, var gameScore = new this.gameScoreObject. Just checking. Not sure if it will work ;)

Comment: 78% isn't bad. I'm not going to accept an answer if I never received a satisfactory one.

Comment: what is error.code? what does the chrome debugger console say if you call console.warn(gameScore) in your error handler?

Comment: @bklimt Error code is -1. `console.warn(gameScore)` returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it's hard to pinpoint the mistake, but here are some ideas:

1. **Look at the response from the request:** In Chrome, `View->Developer->Developer Tools`, click on the Network tab, and try submitting your form. You should see a new request entry come up (probably in red, since yours fails). Click on it and check the response to see if you get a useful error.
2. Check your settings on the `GameScore` table in your Data Browser: Click on `More->Permissions` and ensure that you have `Create` set to `Public`.